# How to print name of class in Python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to find the syntax to print the name of my classes.  Given the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class a:
    whatever  = 0

foo = a()
bar = a()
listOfClasses = [foo,bar]

for l in listOfClasses:
    print l 
    #I'm trying to find the syntax to print the name of the class (eg foo and bar)
```

Comment: That's not the name of your class, that's the name of your variables that hold instances of a class. The class name is "a". The best you'll get is to look at the `locals()` dictionary and find values that are instances of the class you want.

Comment: The name of the class in both cases is `a`. You're trying to find the name of the variable originally assigned, and it's simply not possible.

Comment: @vanza: It's a fine point, but "variables" in Python don't hold *instances*. Variables are *names* bound to objects that exist somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

From your example, you're looking for the name of the instance (`foo` and `bar`). In a nutshell, there isn't a way to do it since there could be multiple named variables pointing to the same instance.

If you're looking for the name of the **class** (i.e. `a`), you could use `l.__class__.__name__`. However, this is not totally bullet-proof either:

```
In [10]: class A(object): pass
   ....: 

In [11]: A().__class__.__name__
Out[11]: 'A'

In [12]: Z = A

In [13]: Z().__class__.__name__
Out[13]: 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get this information, because in Python objects do not have names as such (only *references* to objects have names). Consider:

```
foo = a()
bar = foo # bar is now another name for foo

lst = [foo, bar] # both elements refer to the *same* object
```

In this case, what would your hypothetical "name" function print for each element of `lst`? To show that both elements refer to the same object:

```
print [id(x) for x in lst]
```

will print the same `id` twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: `instance.__class__.__name__`

so in your case: `a = foo.__class__.__name__`

or `b = bar.__class__.__name__`

`a` and `b` are of type string.